# How do I get the rate vote number?

Tags: 7, rating

How do I get the rate vote number, e.g. the number [after "funny," "angry," or "mad"](http://drupal.org/node/899826)?
I looked for the values in the database, but I didn't find a column that stores it.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the rate module, like many such modules it uses the [voting api](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi).

You should use [votingapi_select_results()](http://api.lullabot.com/votingapi_select_results) to get the results. The $criteria array that you pass to it will be

```
$criteria = array(
    'content_type' => $content_type,
    'content_id' => $content_id,
    'tag' => $widget->tag,
  );
```

I have only skimmed the code but I belive that $content_type and $content_id are node type and node id. The $widget->tag will be specific to your widget.

Comment: i put this code in the node.tpl.php, there is no any output.$criteria = array(
    'content_type' => $node->type,
    'content_id' => $node->id,
    'tag' => $widget->tag,
  );echo votingapi_select_results($criteria ) .what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You will need to work out your own widget tag. If you look at your $node structure the widget info should be either in $node->content[$widget_name] or in $node->$widget_name

Comment: i'm sorry, i echo $node->content[$widget_name] and $node->$widget_name there is nothing print.

Comment: You'll have to work out what the widget name is, that will be specific to your set up. do var_dump($node) and have a look

Comment: i echo votingapi_select_results($criteria ) ,the resule is  Array

Comment: i print_r($node),there is no anything about the widget name. when i used the following code. it can output something.$widgets = rate_get_active_widgets('node', $node->type);
 print_r($widgets); the tag=vote. when i instead the 'tag' => vote, then  echo votingapi_select_results($criteria ) .the result is array

Comment: if you just look in the database table, you can see what the tag name is for certain votes, use the same one

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy French , your Solution worked well for me (drupal 7) if you alter the array indexes like this:

```
$criteria = array(
    'entity_type' => $content_type,  //ALTERED
    'entity_id' => $content_id,      //ALTERED
    'tag' => $voting_api_tag,
);
$res = votingapi_select_results($criteria);
```

You can get  `$voting_api_tag` (when `$content_type=='node'`) if you print out the node (e.g. `dsm($node)`). In my case the value was stored in

`$node->field_vote['und'][0]['votingapi_tag']`

Cheers